# restart mod_python without restarting apache?

Tags: apache-2.2

How can I restart `mod_python` without restarting Apache orforce python.py-files to reload ?

Comment: How are you serving your python?  mod_python, cgi, something else?

Comment: python (mainly trac) is loaded via mod_python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mod_python is not a separate program from Apache, it is just some code that runs as part of Apache itself. So you can't restart or reload mod_python without restarting or reloading Apache.

You can get mod_python to automatically reload the main script whenever it changes by putting the [directive](http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/dir-other-par.html)

```
PythonAutoReload on
```

in your Apache configuration.

Note that mod_python is becoming deprecated in favor of [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/), which does allow you to run Python code as a separate process that can be restarted independently of Apache.

Comment: PythnAutoReload does NOT result in automatic reloading for arbitrary Python code file changes. It only works for special handler script files managed directly by mod_python. When using Trac, there will be no such handler files being used and so option does nothing.

Comment: @Graham: thanks for pointing that out, I edited accordingly. I've been using WSGI for long enough that I've evidently forgotten how mod_python works ;-)

Comment: OK, I will give mod_wsgi a try. With the help of both of you, I do accept this as the answer.